# Android Fragments in FragmentTabHost keep overlapping

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity that utilizes a FragmentTabHost with three tabs, each with a different fragment. Each fragment has a listview and upon clicking on an item in the listview, another fragment with information is added to the backstack. The problem is that if that new fragment is called and I switch to another tab..the new fragment overlaps the fragments on the other tabs. How do I fix this? I'm guessing I need to overrirde OnTabSelected? But not sure what to put in there.

This is how I'm adding the fragments:

```
CheckpointFragment fragment = CheckpointFragment.newInstance(data);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.realtabcontent,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```